# Running exe file on ubuntu arm64

Tags: windows, ubuntu, arm, virtual-machine, arm64

I have a oracle cloud server with ubuntu 22.04 on arm64. I want to run an executable windows file on it. To be specific, I want to install TikTok Live Studio, which is currently only available for Windows as an 64 Bit application exe. Obviously it won´t run that easy on ubuntu arm64.
With my knowledge it is not possible to just setup a windows environment on my oracle vm.

So what is the most simple step for me to achieve this so I can run TikTok Live Studio?

I am informed about qemu, box64 and wine. But as I am a complete noob on this, it is very hard for me to setup something, which works. So I am happy if you can help me out. Please descripe to me everything easy understandable

Comment: Arm64 is an architecture distinct from the x86 architecture that your exe is likely compiled for.  This in addition to the fact that you are hoping to run a windows exe in a linux environment.  Thus, you will need to run both qemu and wine, I suppose.  This might make for a fun challenge / experiment but is not going to be practical.  Can you start by getting an Oracle instance that is x86 and then run wine on that? (still unlikely to work... do you have any indication that your application is supported on wine?)

Comment: Thank you for your help, i think it should be possible to take a x86 architecture, but only with linux. I thought every exe application can be executed with wine, but like you say I do not think it is supported by wine. Is there no other way but using wine to run an exe on linux? And can wine run only some specific, supported executable?

Comment: Different apps have different levels of "brokenness" when they run on wine.  I'm not that experienced with it, maybe someone else will weigh in.  They have a compatibility lookup, but you'd need an account with them: https://appdb.winehq.org/ .  Good luck

Comment: Is TikTok Live Studio distributed as an ARM64 executable?  If not, then the only way you could possibly run it on this machine is in emulation (e.g. qemu), which will probably make it at least 10 times slower.  I assume that's not acceptable, so this idea is likely a non-starter.

Comment: Realistically speaking, what you need to do is pony up the money for an x86 Windows cloud instance.  I don't think anything else is going to work reliably if at all.

Comment: The TikTok website currently says "Only supports 64-bit Windows 10 or newer". I think you will have an easier time if you try to run this application on x64 Windows. Trying to debug why an application does not work when you run it on the wrong operating system using the wrong architecture is probably beyond the scope of the support this website can offer.